# iOS: UITableView - wrong automatic height in editing mode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to display a table with custom cells. Each cell has 2 labels and each UILabel can have 2 lines of text at most.
So I have something like this:

[image: A cell with 2 UILabels]

The tableView should calculate the height of each cell automatically because it may vary from cell to cell depending on how long the text is in each UILabel.

```swift
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 106
```

I also want to display this table in editing mode with a checkmark at the left side of each cell and an accessory view at the right side. So I've added this:

```swift
    tableView.isEditing = true
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

and this:

```swift
    cell.editingAccessoryType = .detailButton
```

And it all actually looks pretty well except for one thing.

The problem is that it seems like the UITableView calculates the height for each cell without taking into consideration the checkmark at the left side. For example, if the text in the first label can fit into a single line without the checkmark even though it cannot fit with the checkmark selected, the height of the cell won't adjust properly and as seen in the image below the second label's text is cropped.

Here is a screenshot with texts of either the first or second UILabel in each cell is cropped to 1 line because of that (on iPhone 5 screen width):

[image: Cropped labels]

Does somebody know how to solve this problem without manually calculating the height for each cell?

PS: I've [attached this example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3BUh28QHd4LcnNtamdNazBiLVk) so you could check it yourself.

Comment: Give bottom constrain of your bottom label some constant value.Now it is some thing like <=0.for example you can set it to 0,1,2 etc

Comment: @Vikky unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: I have checked your project its working fine for me after the change i told you

Comment: @Vikky It's odd. Are you checking it on a device with the same screen size? Could you send me an archive with the fixed version so that I could check it?

Comment: I checked in 7 plus after increasing font size to 25 ,because all text was just coming in single line with your given font size.I think you are still setting some wrong constraint.

Comment: @Vikky I just checked it on 7 plus and with 25 font size and the problem still exists. The bottom constraint is set to equal 1 (not greater or equal). Nothing else besides this constraint and font size was changed. Here are the pics: [Constraints](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3BUh28QHd4La3VVT1M1ZWpCVTA), [Result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3BUh28QHd4LbmhyblZOcHN2ckk)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150795/discussion-between-vikky-and-artem-mikhailov).

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at your project and some minor changes are needed to do so.

- First, Select the label's inside the `UItableVIewCell` and click on the `Attributes inspector` button and set the `Lines` property to " 0 ".
- Then set the `Line Break` to `Word Wrap` as shown below in the image.
  [image]

This will surely work as i am currently working on something like this and it works pretty fine for me.